# Unable to open document file (pdf)

Tags: 14.04

I have some documents that can't be opened with document viewer...
file type Microsoft visual studio solution (text/plain) is not supported.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing as for the type of file you want to open: the title says “pdf”, the body says “visual studio solution”. What's the file extension? Can you run `file /path/to/your/file` and tell us the output of that command?

Comment: It appears that Visual Studio Solution files (.sln) can be opened in Linux, indeed in Ubuntu. I don't have any Visual Studio Solutions or Visual Studio Project files to test this on, so instead of answering I will give you the link, so that you can test it for yourself: [How to Open Visual Studio 2013 Solution in MonoDevelop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119701/how-to-open-visual-studio-2013-solution-in-monodevelop/131526#131526). This answer was accepted for Linux Mint, so it should work for Ubuntu too with similar file formats. MonoDevelop is in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Hey the out come when tried to open "that specific file is.... - unable to open document "file:///home/dmsilversoul/downloads/esoteric-healing-a-treatise-on-the-seven-rays-vol-4.pdf".
"file type Microsoft visual studio solution (text/plain) is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

you should have to install wine and then using wine you can install whole Microsoft Office

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? Your answer looks right, but it needs some more detail to become a [good answer](/help/how-to-answer).